# Expression preceding parentheses?

Tags: c

I'm very new to programming and I'm trying to create a simple delay, but I keep getting the error - "expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type".

This code is for a game, it's supposed to delay the racket movement slightly.

```
void AI(void)
{
    unsigned int delay = 1000;

    if (yR2 > yBall)
    {
        if (yR2 > RACKET ) 
        {
            delay(1000);
            yR2--; 
        }
    }
```

I have no idea why this is not working, I've been trying for ages. What is wrong with it and why am I getting that error?

edit:

i've updated the code. this seems correct, but when i try to use the delay, the whole screen is kind of delayed instead of just the racket (yR2) as intended.

why is this?

```
void delay(int n)
{
volatile int i;
for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
  ;
}


void AI(void)
{
if (yR2 > yBall)
{
if (yR2 > RACKET) 
{
   delay(1000);
yR2--;
}
}
```

Comment: `delay` in your code is a variable of `unsigned int`. If there is such a function declared before, it is being masked (overridden) by that variable

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). **use the debugger `gdb`***

Comment: First of all your code snippet is missing 2 closing `}`

Comment: Kninnug, can you please explain how i would resolve this issue. i'm extremely new to programming and i'm having trouble understanding some things. there is no function declared before called delay, the only "delay" there is in the whole code is unsigned int delay

Comment: Standard C does not have any "delay" function. So you have to use something platform-specific to sleep. If you are using some game framework (such as SDL), it probably has an event loop, and then you don't actually want to sleep, but to schedule a callback to be called after some time. Even if you have your own main loop, you will probably discover having a delay in it will cause problems... If you are using threads, then... learn things for a few months before doing that :).

Comment: The instruction `delay(1000);` means there is a *function* of that name, taking the argument value `1000`.  So `unsigned int delay = 1000;` is irrelevant, because it is never used.

Comment: i'm programming a microcontroller and i've used the delay function before

Comment: If you have a delay function you want to call, then stop shadowing it by defining a variable with the same name. Which is to say -- rename your integer to be called something other than `delay`, so it doesn't interfere with your ability to call the *function* named `delay`.

Comment: Please don't reword your question in ways that hide the original.  Also, your `delay()` function doesn't do anything, which means it's likely to be optimized away entirely by any decent optimizing compiler.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The `volatile` means that it can't be optimized away.

Comment: You posted your question, people answered and commented on it, and then you changed your question, making the answers obsolete. Don't do that. If you'll post a new question with the code you have now, there's probably a reasonable answer, but I'm not going to post it here. (Hint: `delay(1000)` is likely to take very little time to execute. Hint: There are better ways to delay for a specified amount of time, but they're system-specific.)

Comment: @AndrewHenle what do you mean it doesn't do anything? what do i need to change? forgive my unintelligent questions like i've said before, i've been programming for literally 2 days.

Comment: I've rolled back your most recent edit. The question now corresponds to the correct answer you've already received. Your edits are still visible in the edit history if you want to post a new question.

Comment: when i run code that i edited and have shown in the original post and i set the delay to around 50000, everything is delay on the screen and not just the racket (yR2) as intended. why is this?

Comment: Your original question was answered. Post a new one.

Answer (score 5):

The error is referring to this line:

```
delay(1000);
```

Here you're (apparently) trying to call `delay` as a function.

However, `delay` is declared as:

```
unsigned int delay = 1000;
```

It's just a number, not a function, hence you can't call it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. how would i resolve this issue? do i need to create a function and if so, what would it look like. i'm not been programming long, sorry for the not so intelligent questions.

Comment: @nothing909 Why did you put `unsigned int delay = 1000;` and `delay(1000);` in your code in the first place?

Comment: i just don't have the best programming knowledge and didn't fully understand what i was doing. it was declaring the variable int delay... and then calling it delay(1000). i've now discovered thats not how it works..

Comment: What do you expect a variable of type int to do when you call it? If you don't tell us what you *want* the code to do, we can't tell you how to change it to get what you want.

Comment: @nothing909 What do you mean by "calling a variable"? That's ... not a thing.

Comment: ...well, it's a thing if your variable is a function pointer. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Even then I'd argue you're actually calling the thing the variable is pointing to. :-)

Comment: how do i resolve my error then, what do i need to add or change for it to work

Comment: @nothing909 You still haven't explained what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: the code is for a pong game. i want to delay the racket (yR2) movement slightly

Comment: @nothing909 You said you're using a microcontroller and it has a `delay` function. So what happens if you remove the `unsigned int delay = 1000;` line?

Comment: it says delay(1000) was declared implicitly.

Comment: does anyone have any idea without using delay or sleep function i can just add a simple delay into my code provided?

Comment: @nothing909, you say your platform provides a delay function -- then find the header that defines that function, and `#include` it. Writing your own will be much less power-efficient than taking advantage of platform support, so folks who care about best practices would be acting appropriately to decline to assist you in doing so.

Comment: @nothing909, ...anyhow, the fact that you don't know how to include a delay doesn't change the fact that the correct way to stop getting this syntax error *is* to stop declaring a variable whose name conflicts with a function you want to call. If you have a separate question about where to get a `delay` function on whatever specific embedded platform you're developing for, that's a separate question and should be asked independently.